# wordpress custom endpoint multiple params

Tags: php, plugin-development, rest-api, wp-api

I'm trying to create a route in my store, to receive notifications from an API, but every time I test the route I created, I get this error message `No route was found matching the URL and request method`

```
function notifications_cbt_func($request) {
     return $request;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
     register_rest_route( 'cbt-api/v1', '/notifications/', array(
       'methods' => 'GET',
       'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
     ) );
});
```

when I make my call via postman always gives this error

```
GET: https://planetmusicexpress.com/wp-json/cbt-api/v1/notifications/?merchant_id=765&resource=\/orders\/MBR010131&topic=orders
```

this code of mine is inside a plugin that I created, I'm sure my plugin is working, because I have others called within the same file as this code that are working. Can anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I know my route works because it appears here `https://planetmusicexpress.com/index.php/wp-json`

what I don't know is to mount her call on get, or mount the regular expression so that it looks the same as it is on my get

**EDIT**

```
function notifications_cbt_func($request) {
     $merchant_id = $request->get_param( 'merchant_id' );
     $resource    = $request->get_param( 'resource' );

     // Get all the parameters:
     $params = $request->get_params();

     return json_encode($$params);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
     register_rest_route( 'cbt-api/v1', '/notifications/', array(
       'methods' => 'GET',
       'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
     ) );
});

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
     register_rest_route( 'cbt-api/v1', '/notifications/', array(
       'methods' => 'POST',
       'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
     ) );
});
```

I made the changes suggested in the responses, but my route both get and post are returning null when I do this:

```
https://planetmusicexpress.com/wp-json/cbt-api/v1/notifications/?merchant_id=765&resource=MBR010131&topic=orders
```

Comment: I visited the [endpoint](https://planetmusicexpress.com/wp-json/cbt-api/v1/notifications/?merchant_id=765&resource=\/orders\/MBR010131&topic=orders) and it worked fine?

Comment: I managed to stop giving error, but I can't get what I pass in parameters, I put the regular expression, it keeps giving the error.

Comment: I hope the answer helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment, your [endpoint](https://planetmusicexpress.com/wp-json/cbt-api/v1/notifications/?merchant_id=765&resource=/orders/MBR010131&topic=orders) worked fine for me.

And you said,

> I managed to stop giving error, but I can't get what I pass in
>   parameters, I put the regular expression, it keeps giving the error.

So not sure about that "regular expression" thing, but you can use `$request->get_param()` to get a specific parameter, or `$request->get_params()` to get all parameters in the request (e.g. the URL):

```php
function notifications_cbt_func( $request ) {
    // Get specific parameters:
    $merchant_id = $request->get_param( 'merchant_id' );
    $resource    = $request->get_param( 'resource' );

    // Get all the parameters:
    $params = $request->get_params();

    //...
}
```

And note that in the above examples, the `$request` variable is a [`WP_REST_Request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) instance, so please check that link for the class methods, properties, etc.

You should also check the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments). :)

### Update

In response to the comment or the edited question,

In your callback (`notifications_cbt_func()`), there's no need for the `json_encode()` because WordPress REST API endpoints indeed return a JSON-encoded string, i.e. a JSON response.

So just do `return $params;` or whatever that needs to be returned.

And about the "*but my route both GET and POST are returning null*" — That's because you used `$$params` which (is a `null` and) should be `$params`.

Also, there's no need to call `register_rest_route()` multiple times for the same route (`/cbt-api/v1/notifications` in your case). Just call it once with the third parameter being an *array of endpoints*:

```php
register_rest_route( 'cbt-api/v1', '/notifications', array(
    array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
    ),
    array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
    ),
) );
```

And for the exact same callback (and parameters), you can simply supply an *array of methods*:

```php
register_rest_route( 'cbt-api/v1', '/notifications', array(
    'methods'  => array( 'GET', 'POST' ),
    'callback' => 'notifications_cbt_func',
) );
```

Comment: Tanks, but I made the changes suggested in the responses, but my route both get and post are returning null

Comment: Check the "Update" part. And btw, sorry, I was off-line until an hour ago.